# print a char in sqlserver in a same line within while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, while-loop

I need to produce

```
*    
**     
***    
****    
*****
```

as output in sql server

```
DECLARE @x INT ;
DECLARE @y INT ;

SET @x = 1;
set @y=0;

while @x <=5
begin
while @y<@x
    begin
    print('*')
    set @y=@y+1
    end
print ''+char(1)
set @y=0;
set @x=@x+1
end
```

But I can't print * in the same line each * is printing in individual line

Comment: print replicate('*',@x)

Comment: I wouldn't use a loop here at all.

Comment: We don't use tsql to "print" in the first place. Wrong tool, wrong learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a silly inner loop when you can just do:

```
print replicate('*', 5)
```

and put that into a loop (if you want `print` instead of `select`).

```
set @x = 1;

while @x <=5
begin
    print replicate('*', @x);
    set @x = @x + 1;
end;
```

Comment: Is it supported by all SQL Version?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale . . . It has been around for a long, long time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option that doesn't use looping. In the real world a tally/numbers table would make short work of this.

```
select replicate('*', n)
from
(
    values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
) x(n)
```

Comment: how does this work? where to read what is x(n)

Comment: @AuthorProxy that FROM is using a Table Valued Constructor. The "x" is the alias for the derived table. And (n) is naming the column in the table, similar to the way you can name columns in a cte.

Comment: finally I understand this ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Try inbuilt Replicate() method in SQL SERVER

```
DECLARE @var int                
SET @var = 1   

DECLARE @rows int  /*number of rows you want*/
SET @rows = 5 

WHILE (@var <= @rows)   
BEGIN                       
  PRINT Replicate('*', @var)     
  SET @var = @var + 1            
END
```

more details : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replicate.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and populate that with what you want to print, and then print that after all your loops.

See code below, I commented out your prints and used variables instead.

```
DECLARE @x INT ;
DECLARE @y INT ;
DECLARE @ValueToPrint VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @x = 1;
set @y=0;

while @x <=5
    begin
        WHILE @y<@x
            BEGIN
                SET @ValueToPrint += '*'
                --print('*')
                SET @y=@y+1
            END


        SET @ValueToPrint += ''+char(1)
        --PRINT ''+char(1)
        -- maybe you want to print it here, if so print the variable here if so uncomment these 2 lines
        -- PRINT @ValueToPrint
        -- SET @ValueToPrint = ''

        SET @y=0;
        SET @x=@x+1
    END

PRINT @ValueToPrint
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
;WITH nums AS
       (SELECT 1 AS value
        UNION ALL
        SELECT value + 1 AS value
        FROM nums
        WHERE nums.value <=5)
    SELECT replicate('*',value)
    FROM nums
```